# Bounded Linear "Change of Basis"

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a separable Banach space and $x,y \in E$.  Does there necessarily exist a bijective bounded linear operator $A\in B(E)$ such that
$$
Ax =y,
$$
such that $A^{-1}$ is also a bounded linear operator?  I know this to be true in finite dimensions and on the separable Hilbert space, but what about in general?

Comment: Maybe you can construct it using a Schauder basis?

Comment: The problem is trivial if $x=0$ or $y=0$. Also if $A$ is bounded and bijective then $A^{-1}$ is guaranteed to be bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent, then the problem is unsolvable (if exactly one of $x,y$ is zero) or trivial ($A$ is multiple of identity).

Assume that $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent. Define functionals $f,g\in X^*$ by
$f(x)=1$, $f(y)=0$, $g(x)=0$, $g(y)=1$, and extension by Hahn-Banach.

Define projection operator
$$
Pz:= f(z)x + g(z)y.
$$
Define
$$
Az := f(z)y + g(z)x + (I-P)(z)= z - (f(z)-g(z))(x-y).
$$
The idea of the construction is: exchange $x$ an $y$ on the span of both, on $\ker f\cap \ker g$ act as identity.

Then $Ax=y$ and $Ay=x$. In addition $A^2=I$:
We have
$$
f(Az) = f(z) -(f(z)-g(z))=g(z),
$$
$$
g(Az) = g(z) + (f(z)-g(z))=f(z).
$$
Then
$$
A^2(z) = Az + (f(z)-g(z))(x-y) = z.
$$
This implies that $A$ is bijective. Obviously, $A$ is bounded.